# Non-nominal type "Self" doesn't support explicit initialisation (protocol extension for enums)

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

I'm trying to find a way of adding a "count" variable to enums that allows the number of cases to be quantified. This is straightforward and works well when hard coded into each enum but a logical extension is to make it a protocol extension...but I run into the above error.

Reading up other posts suggest that the compiler doesn't have enough information to instantiate the enum. I've tried adding associated types but the error persists. Is this just something I'm going to have to give up on? It's not hugely important but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Code as follows:

```
protocol CountableEnum: RawRepresentable {
    static var count: Int { get }
}

extension CountableEnum {
    static var count: Int {
        var max = 0
        while let _ = self(rawValue: max) { max += 1 }
        return max
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the error itself, but keep in mind that your `count` variable won't always contain the correct value, since `enum` raw values can be set manually as well, in which case they don't have to start from 0 and don't have to be incremented by 1.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware that this is a risk but this protocol is only going to be used for internal testing processes (generating random enums) and won't be part of a public API. I may put a test case in place to check for this scenario depending on how paranoid I'm feeling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper `Self` reference instead of `self` and constrain your extension to only types with the `RawValue` of `Int`.

```
protocol CountableEnum: RawRepresentable {
    static var count: Int { get }
}

extension CountableEnum where RawValue == Int {
    static var count: Int {
        var max = 0
        while let _ = Self(rawValue: max) { max += 1 }
        return max
    }
}
```

Comment: `while Self(rawValue: max) != nil`

Comment: Excellent - as suspected the complier just needed a bit more assistance, I just wasn't familiar with how to define the constraints. Thanks for the assist :-)

Answer (score 0):

`RawRepresentable` have an associatedtype `RawValue`, in your example it doesn't specify that it is an `Int`. If you constraint protocol extension with `where` as in example below it should work fine.

```
protocol CountableEnum: RawRepresentable {
  static var count: Int { get }
}

extension CountableEnum where RawValue == Int {
  static var count: Int {
    var max = 0
    while let _ = self.init(rawValue: max) { max += 1 }
    return max
  }
}
```